Trying to derive some properties of geometric brownian motion
I am trying to derive some properties of geometric brownian motion:
$dS_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t dW_t$
I am interested in analyzing paths that 'survive' a lower boundary $X$ i.e. always stay above $X$ during time $T$.
I have found that the probability of survival can be calculated by:
$P\left( S_t > X, \, \forall t \in [0, T] \right) = \Phi\left( \frac{\ln\left(\frac{S_0}{X}\right) + \left(\mu - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2\right) T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}} \right) - \left( \frac{X}{S_0} \right)^{\frac{2\mu}{\sigma^2}-1} \Phi\left( \frac{-\ln\left(\frac{S_0}{X}\right) + \left(\mu - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2\right) T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}} \right)$
I am interested in three things:

What is the expected value of $S_T$ of all the paths that 'survived' and never went below $X$
$\mathbb{E}[S_T \mid S_t > X, \forall t \in [0, T]]$
What is the variance of $S_T$ of the survived paths?
For the paths that touched or went below $X$: How can I calculate the expected time the price went below?

Ideally I'm looking for a formula and a simple proof, but if someone could give me a link to a paper or search terms that would be a great help too. Thank you!

You could start writing out exactly what you need

Call $M_T = \min_{t<T} S_t$
for the mean, I guess you want $\mathbb{E}[S_T \mid M_T > X] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[S_T \mathbb{1}_{M_T > X}]}{P(M_t>X)}$
2nd moment, similar: $\mathbb{E}[S_T^2 \mid M_T > X] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[S_T^2 \mathbb{1}_{M_T > X}]}{P(M_t>X)}$

And from this the variance. Do you agree so far? (For your point 3, it would be better to spell it out, it smells of local time).
You already have a formula for $P$. The numerator for the mean is the same as a 0-strike down-and-out call (which there are formulas for).
The only way I know how to get $\mathbb{E}[S_T^2 \mid M_T > X]$ is via replication with a portfolio of down-and-out calls (with multiple strikes).
If you do the above, double check you are handling the discount factor correctly.
Alternatively, you could study the derivation of the $P$ you copied above and see if you can get the joint distribution of $S_T$ and $M_T$.
You can find something very similar in Karatzas & Shreve in proposition 8.1, but it is for a Brownian Motion without a drift (which you do have). This question asks the same thing: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3333028/joint-density-function-of-brownian-motion-with-drift-and-its-running-maximum
Once you get it, you just integrate it.
